# How to create every pairwise combination in Excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have an exhaustive list of 2-digit zip codes in columns 1 and 2 (01 to 99). I want to create a third column that will contain every pairwise combination of two-digit zipcodes. So that my data will look something like this where column 3 contains every pairwise combination of columns 1 and 2 (9801 rows).

```
col1 col2  col3
01    01   01 to 01
02    02   02 to 02
03    03   03 to 03
04    04   04 to 04
05    05   05 to 05
06    06   06 to 06
.     .       .
.     .       .
99    99  99 to 99
```

Is there a way to code this into a simple vba script?

Comment: You could use a quick formula: `=A2 & " to " & B2`

Comment: col3 isn't the same length as col1 and col2. The example snippet doesn't illustrate it well but I need every pairwise combination. So col3 will contain 9801 rows. ( 01 to 01, 01 to 02, ..., 01 to 99, 02 to 01,..., 02 to 99, etc)

Comment: So what have you tried?  You will need two loops, I suggest you load everything into arrays, with another array as the output then assign that output array to the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pertinent to your task, you can use the following Excel VBA code snippet:

```
Sub ColumnConcatenation()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Const max = 99
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To max
        For j = 1 To max
            Range("C" & (i - 1) * max + j) = Range("A" & i) & " to " & Range("B" & j)
        Next j
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: If you change the 9's to 99's this works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: That's right: you can extend the solution to use any Integer. Btw, as FYI: this particular problem translates to the calculation of the Cartesian Product of two sets. Best regards,

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help!

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I have almost no VBA experience, but this was easier to figure out than I originally thought.

```
Sub pairwise()

Dim x As Integer
Dim x2 As Integer
Dim x3 As Double

x3 = 1

For x = 1 To 99
    For x2 = 1 To 99

    Cells(x3, 5) = Cells(x, 1)
    Cells(x3, 6) = Cells(x2, 2)

    x3 = x3 + 1

    Next
Next
End Sub
```

This creates 2 columns which I can then Concatenate by pasting the formula `=E1&" to "&F1` in `G1:G9801`. If there's a more elegant way of doing this I'd gladly accept that as an answer.